# Rotating a curve $z = f(x)$ about the $z$-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

> Let $z = f(x)$ be a function from $[0, \infty)$ into $\mathbb{R}$ living in the $xz$-plane, for example. Create a surface $z = g(x,y)$ by rotating the graph of $f$ about the $z$-axis.

In other words, the surface is such that $g(x,mx) = f(x)$ for all $m \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $x \in [0, \infty)$. Is there a general method for defining $g$ explicitly given $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in this case you have a function $z = f(x)$ in this case to obtain $g$ by revolving a function around the $z$-axis that lives in the $xz$-plane, replace $x$ by $\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ 
So you would have $z-f(x) = 0 \implies z-f(\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=0$. Since you are on the positive axis simply use $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Of course. With a one-dimensional domain, $x$ is the distance from the axis. With a two-dimensional domain, I need to provide $f$ with the distance from $(x,y)$ to the axis. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ is expanded to $ (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta ), $ we have $ x\rightarrow r. $ So

$$ z= f(x) \rightarrow f(r) $$

In this way you express that a given meridian belongs to a surface of revolution.

For example the meridian

$$ y = c \cosh \frac {z}{c}.$$

becomes a subset of

$$ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = c \cosh \frac {z}{c}$$

so in general

$$ g(x,y) =   g( \sqrt{x^2+y^2} ) = g(r) $$

becomes a function of a *single* independent variable.